# Day 6, HttpListenerException is winning

Tags: asp.net, json, azure, alexa-skills-kit

Unhandled Exception: System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is denied.  Building a demo Alexa Skill using AWS Lambda to send query and credentials to Azure Web App running at http://alexaintent.azurewebsites.net.  No problem connecting but, even after asking nicely, cannot get port 80 to listen.  Http, not Https.  All I see now is numbers.  Must eat.
2016-11-29T13:15:36  PID[56848] Error       Unhandled Exception: System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is denied

2016-11-29T13:15:36  PID[56848] Error          at System.Net.HttpListener.SetupV2Config()

2016-11-29T13:15:36  PID[56848] Error          at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()

2016-11-29T13:15:36  PID[56848] Error          at ProxyIntent1.Program.Main(String[] args)

2016-11-29 13:14:36 ALEXAINTENT GET /intent request=%7B%22locale%22%3A%22en-US%22%2C%22timestamp%22%3A%222016-10-27T21%3A06%3A28Z%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22IntentRequest%22%2C%22requestId%22%3A%22amzn1.echo-api.request.EdwRequestId.80c95f4f-16b4-4c00-9cd3-d65b495fb08a%22%2C%22intent%22%3A%7B%22slots%22%3A%7B%22Color%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22Color%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22blue%22%7D%7D%2C%22name%22%3A%22MyColorIsIntent%22%7D%7D&session=%7B%22new%22%3Afalse%2C%22sessionId%22%3A%22amzn1.echo-api.session.SessionId.adb7e494-4afa-4892-9f46-7819e0090403%22%2C%22attributes%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22user%22%3A%7B%22userId%22%3A%22amzn1.ask.account.AEPAXARAQWGW76N6ILPEJY676JAVHDL457YLBCOAEUWKE727P5I3P5MS64IQFTZZH4L7QZYTHCKC7OP3ZCYHCK6JA3DXB6RLPYUVBLXZZJ2PE76Y2DP2KDB4EIB6NCZ4YTIVFF4VRLTZAGIRGPFXLP3ZMYO7ELSDCG7DGIABWMUZ4R7KDC6UNWB6RJK2B7YMCNAB3HPRMKMCG5Y%22%7D%2C%22application%22%3A%7B%22applicationId%22%3A%22amzn1.ask.skill.a15efd21-ff4f-4fe0-93c6-5a593390ea38%22%7D%7D&X-ARR-LOG-ID=3da8e463-ed65-4d28-ad4d-0097ab149f87 80 - 54.145.163.135 - - - alexaintent.azurewebsites.net 404 0 2 475 2367 15

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: How do I mitigate this error?

Comment: Let me understand a little bit more. So you created Alexa skill and you confirmed this is working via the test in the AWS Alexa developer portal?

Comment: I figured out a way around it with a different framework.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

used the slight framework from GitHub and got that to work